# Tools for Full Window Coverage

Tags: python, user-interface, pycharm, kivy

I have two difficulties to resolve:

- Is there a tool to make the image completely cover the window I open?
  for information: the size of my image is 1368x768.
- also I manage to put my window in dark mode, although I specified it in the code on line 12.

how to fix these two problems ?

https://imgur.com/ootQu5P

https://imgur.com/8oPBK5B

any help would be greatly appreciated !

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For the first question: You can simply modify the content of the kv file as follows:

```
<testApp>:
    Screen:
        Image:
            source: "pic.png"
            size_hint: 1, 1
            allow_stretch: True
            keep_ratio: False
```

This will make it resize to fit the entire window and position itself at the top-left corner by default (without needing to specify `pos_hint` unless you require specific positioning. Please note that there are some spelling errors in your file like this, such as using 'halgin' instead of 'halign'.).

Alternatively, you can use the updated syntax like this:

```py
fit_mode: "fill"
```

This statement refers to the following in the KivyMD documentation:

```markdown
To control how the image should be adjusted to fit inside the widget box, you should use the fit_mode property. Available options include:

"scale-down": maintains aspect ratio without stretching.

"fill": stretches to fill widget, may cause distortion.

"contain": maintains aspect ratio and resizes to fit inside widget.

"cover": maintains aspect ratio and stretches to fill widget, may clip
```

Regarding the second issue, you need to modify `theme_style` instead of `theme__style`. Therefore, the correct way is:

```
self.theme_cls.theme_style = 'Dark'
```

Reason: This is a conventionally established property name within the KivyMD framework. For further information, you can refer to its documentation.

I have modified your program, and here's the complete content:

```py
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen


class testApp(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)


class MyApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = 'Dark'
        return testApp()
    def change_theme(self):
        if self.theme_cls.theme_style == 'Dark':
            self.theme_cls.theme_style = 'Light'
        else:
            self.theme_cls.theme_style = 'Dark'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Window.size = (1100, 600)
    Builder.load_file("main.kv")
    MyApp().run()
```

```
<testApp>:
    Screen:
        Image:
            source: "pic.png"
            size_hint: 1, 1
            fit_mode: "fill"

        MDLabel:
            text: "cover the window I open"
            font_size: "48dp"
            halign: "center"
            color: app.theme_cls.text_color
            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.4, 'center_y': 0.4}
        MDRaisedButton:
            text: "Click me!"
            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.2}
            on_press: app.change_theme()
            md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color
            text_color: app.theme_cls.text_color
```

Please note that I've added a simple MDRaisedButton to display the status of the theme activation. Normally, you should observe a change in the text color, which indicates that the theme is functioning properly.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment, for the first problem I was able to resolve it, it's good, on the other hand the second problem when I correct what you have just told me, by removing an underscore `theme__style` to -----> `theme_style`,  the program works but the problem still remains the same, the frame of the slot still remains in "light" mode despite the fact that I have just corrected what you just told me !

Comment: @Guts71 I'm uncertain about where the problem lies in your situation. How do you verify whether the light or dark theme is functioning correctly? In any case, I've updated my answer with some content that may potentially address your concerns. I hope it proves helpful to you!